# DIV width like parent DIV (Parent DIV's width is not setted)

Tags: html, css

I have a problema with a dropdown menu.
I have made this code (with the help of w3schools)... :)

The problem is that the div that appears when I go hover a div, the "subdiv" width is not like the parent.

I tried to assign to "select_checkbox".

I solve the problem if I set width of "multi_select" fixed in pixel and then set the width of "select_checkbox" to 100%, but I don't want to set a fixed width for "multi_select".

Is there a way to make it possibile without using javascript?

Thank you

```css
.multi_select {
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
}

.div_select {
  font-size: 14px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #EEE;
  padding: 0px 5px 0px 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.div_select::after {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f0d7";
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

.multi_select_cat:hover .select_checkbox, 
.multi_select_num:hover .select_checkbox{
  display: block;
}

.select_checkbox {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  background: #EEE;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-top: 0px;
  width: inherit;
}

.select_checkbox div {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.select_checkbox div:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #F60;
}

.select_checkbox_show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="multi_select multi_select_num">

  <div class="div_select noselect">
    Numero elementi da mostrare
  </div>

  <div class="select_checkbox">
    <div>10</div>
    <div>20</div>
    <div>30</div>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="multi_select multi_select_cat">

  <div class="div_select noselect">
    Filtra per categoria
  </div>

  <div class="select_checkbox">
    <div><input type="checkbox"> Sistemi</div>
    <div><input type="checkbox"> Strumenti</div>
    <div><input type="checkbox"> Automotive</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add following extra CSS to existing properties

```
.multi_select {
     position: relative;
}

.select_checkbox {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: this is better solution then mine if the fixed width is not needed.

Comment: cool! You can now accept this answer, so that other people with the same question in the future will know this is the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to make .multi_select relative

```
.multi_select {
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  position: relative; // Added
}
```

and than set the .select_checkbox left and right to 0

```
.select_checkbox {
  position: absolute;
    display: none;
    background: #EEE;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-top: 0px;
    width: inherit;
    left: 0; // Added
    right: 0; // Added
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to manually define widths to the container div's

```
.multi_select_num {
    width: 200px;
}

.multi_select_cat {
    width: 135px;
}
```

Comment: *[...] but I don't want to set a fixed width for `.multi_select`*